# How to deny access to whole computer file system for Apache/PHP?

Tags: php, apache, include, filesystems, file-get-contents

My Apache/PHP web server located in "F:\WebServer", but it has access to whole computer file system (not only "F:**WebServer**", but system drive and disk "F:\" too):

[image]

How to restrict Apache/PHP access it? I want only access "F:**WebServer**" folder and files/folders inside it

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do this is to limit the permission of your apache user but I'm not quite sure how to go about this with Windows permissions.

However, The PHP ini includes a directive to restrict the folders PHP will traverse to:-

> **[open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)** *string*
>
> Limit the files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified
>   directory-tree, including the file itself. This directive is NOT
>   affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.